# Infinitely differentiable positive valued function on the real line.

Tags: integration

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow(0,\infty)$ be an infinitely differentiable function with $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t) \,dt =1$. Then show that $f''(a)=0$ for some $a\in R$ .

Comment: What have you tried? A contradiction argument seems adapted for this. Suppose for example (wlog) that $f''(x) > 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$. What does this imply for the integral of $f$?

Comment: Further hint: how are $f'$ and $f''$ related? how are $f$ and $f'$ related?

Comment: Further hint: Since $f$ is infinitely differentiable, $f''$ is continuous.

Comment: How to use integration part ?

Comment: Further hint: Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Comment: Can such f be unbounded?

Comment: can an unbounded, smooth, and positive function integrate to 1?

Comment: Yes it can exist. Try to think graphically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If possible let $f''(x)\ne0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Then either $f''>0$ or $f''<0$ because of IVP of $f''$.

Case1:  $f''>0$
Then $f'$ is increasing. If for some $c \in \mathbb{R}$ $f'(c)>0$ then $f(x)>0$ for all $x\ge c$ which is a contradiction since then as $f>0$ the area under the function f contains rectangular region $\{(x,f(c)):x\ge c\}$ which contradicts that $\int_{-\infty}^{-\infty}fdx=1.$
So $f'(x)<0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ implies that f is strictly decreasing. Now observe that the area under the function f contains $\{(x,f(0)):x\ge 0\}$ again a contradiction. Hence there exist a $c\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f''(c)=0$.

Case2: $f''<0$ it can be done in the similiar way.

Comment: Yeah thanks I understood.